# Running Quartz.net on another server

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have a Windows Forms application where users can define certain tasks to be scheduled, but I want to run them on another server. I was thinking that I could schedule the tasks using Quartz.NET with the AdoJob scheduler, so they will be in a database, and on the same server as the database I would have a Windows Service which could read the scheduled jobs and execute them. How should I do this in Quartz.NET? Or is this not the best approach for my problem?

Update: Here's what I'm trying.

1. Schedule a task from the app using the type name of the class which should be executed

   I tried with Quartz.NET to schedule a job using the name and namespace of the class, but it doesn't work, instead of using a direct reference to it. If this would have worked, the next step would've been to start the windows service and see if I could run the job from there.

   IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.IHelloJob"))
   .WithIdentity("myJobRemote", "remote")
   .StoreDurably()
   .Build();

The exception message says "Job class cannot be null."

2. If I make the first step work, then I'll start the windows service and try to run the job inside of it

Comment: Sure this can likely be done, and something like quartz or similar is likely the right approach, however there will be a learning curve. I suggest getting a scheduling framework and playing with it first before trying to design this in one swoop

Comment: I used Hangfire before, but in this project we're already using Quartz.NET for scheduling some tasks using XML files. The difference is that my tasks are not known at compile time, so the user can go to a screen, pick an interval(daily, weekly, every x weeks on certain days, etc.) and I have to run this on another server. I saw in the Quartz.NET documentation that they talk about .NET Remoting, but my app and the Windows Service are on different servers, so I don't think I can use this.

Comment: You can add and remove tasks /jobs /triggers at runtime

Comment: Yes, but how do you schedule a job that is defined in another assembly that is not referenced by the desktop app?

Comment: Ahh, now we are getting to a more concrete question. Pick a framework, do some research, give some examples of what your have tried, and this will be answered

Comment: I tried with Quartz.NET to schedule a job using the name and namespace of the class, but it doesn't work, instead of using a direct reference to it. If this would have worked, the next step would've been to start the windows service and see if I could run the job from there.


`IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.IHelloJob"))
                    .WithIdentity("myJobRemote", "remote")
                    .StoreDurably()
                    .Build();`
The exception message says "Job class cannot be null."

Comment: This should be in the question

Comment: You have to create shared code.  And that shared code will get deployed in two places.  On the client.  (Here will be the code to create teh jobs/triggers)  and then you need to deploy the shared code on the machine that is your quartz.net server.         That is one of the learning curves of quartz.net..........getting non "hello world" code running on the server.